# How to print custom field value inside shortcode Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to print a Custom field value inside the shortcode I have, I tried the following code but it's not working for me ... what's i can do to make it print the value ?

```
<?php echo [mks_button size="large" title="Download Pdf File" style="rounded" url="(get_field('download_link')<>""?''.get_field('download_link').'':"");" target="_blank" bg_color="#1e73be" txt_color="#FFFFFF" icon="fa-file-pdf-o" icon_type="fa" nofollow="1"]'); ?>
```

**Note:** The Value i want to print inside the url Attribute

Comment: `[mks_button` what is it? i think u have parse error

Comment: i am not expert, but maybe it will work `$url = "test";
echo '[mks_button size="large" title="Download Pdf File" style="rounded" url="'.$url.'" target="_blank" bg_color="#1e73be" txt_color="#FFFFFF" icon="fa-file-pdf-o" icon_type="fa" nofollow="1"]';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try.

```
$url = get_field('download_link');

if($url){
    echo do_shortcode('[mks_button size="large" title="Download Pdf File" style="rounded" url="'. $url .'" target="_blank" bg_color="#1e73be" txt_color="#FFFFFF" icon="fa-file-pdf-o" icon_type="fa" nofollow="1"]'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) method to output a shortcode content.

It would do something like this:

```
$url = get_field('download_link');
if($url){
  echo do_shortcode('[mks_button size="large" title="Download Pdf File" style="rounded" url="'.$url.'" target="_blank" bg_color="#1e73be" txt_color="#FFFFFF" icon="fa-file-pdf-o" icon_type="fa" nofollow="1"]'); ?>
}
```

You could check the `get_field('download_link')` before to prevent double database query, or use `get_field('download_link') ?: ''`. I updated my answer to do this check.

Note: from a PHP template, use `do_shortcode()`, but from a post/page wysiwyg, putting the shortcode while being in "visual mode" should work.